# Naming column and row names in R from another data type

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have an array like this:

```
> columnnames
[1] trade    grain    crude    corn     ship     wheat    acq      interest money.fx earn
> summary(columnnames)
 acq     corn    crude     earn    grain interest money.fx     ship    trade    wheat 
   1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
> str(columnnames)
Factor w/ 10 levels "acq","corn","crude",..: 9 5 3 2 8 10 1 6 7 4
```

and have another like this:

```
> rownames
 [1] "tp" "fn" "fp" "tn" "tpr" "fnr"  "precision" "recall"  "acc"  "Fmeasure"
```

Question is simple: How can I create an empty matrix or table (doesn't matter) with these row and column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
your.matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(rownames), ncol = length(columnnames))
rownames(your.matrix) <- rownames
colnames(your.matrix) <- as.character(columnnames)
```

or

```
your.matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(rownames), ncol = length(columnnames), dimnames = list(rownames, columnnames))
```

Comment: Error in col.names(your.matrix) <- as.character(columnnames) : 
  could not find function "col.names<-"